# PageLayout in module is not updating with GhostableInLibrary proerty set to true

Tags: page-layout, module

After deploying solution, I again made some changes to custom page layout content and deployed. But the page layout is not getting over written old page layout is still there.

tried deleting Page Layout, retracting solution, IIS reset, server restart but nothing worked. Also tried bellow replace content true and allow if exist false. nothing is working please help me.

```
 <File Path="PageLayouts\HRHomePage4ColLayout.aspx" Url="PageLayouts/HRHomePage4ColLayout.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" ReplaceContent="TRUE" Name="HRHomePage4ColLayout.aspx" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="FALSE">
      <Property Name="Title" Value="HR Home Page 4 Col Layout"></Property>
      <Property Name="MasterPageDescription" Value="HR Home Page 4 Col Layout"></Property>
      <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_pagelayout_name;" />
      <Property Name="PublishingPreviewImage" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/WelcomeSplash.png, ~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/WelcomeSplash.png" />
      <Property Name="PublishingAssociatedContentType" Value=";#NewsPageLayout;#0x010003E7FF1F2ECA4F00BF662BB8F89F47CF002269CE9D4E7540A5A1C7DB7BBF22A495;#"></Property>
    </File>
```

For other types its working fine having problem with type only  GhostableInLibrary

Comment: Can you also try adding `Level="Published"` and see if it works.

Comment: i did tried this also still its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i had uploaded initially the `<asp:content>` tag's were in small case, it was fresh upload so it just saved the file to SharePoint cache and SQL server.

When i uploaded after editing it tried to compare the old and new one for the recording the changes(Sharepoint ghostable-in library will save only the changes in the SQL server from second time).

And it was not able to properly recognize the `<asp:content>` tag so i changed it to `<asp:Content>` tag **C** as upper case then it worked.